# How to show pagination using JS List?

Tags: javascript, arrays, pagination

Hello I really need your help I'm new to JAVASCRIPT and I need to implement a pagination alphabetically from a-z I don't know where to start ..  I wish I could have a list of first letters found in the result (I mean, if there is no row beginning with 'a', I don't want the 'a' to be display on the pagination links). Is there any kind of plain Javascript pagination exists ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say you have a list of names instead of rows to paginate. It might be a good idea to group them under their initial character and then set up your pagination accordingly.

```js
 var names = ["aaron", "amber", "bruce", "david", "izzy", "jasmine", "jeniffer", "karen", "lily", "mandy", "marry", "ozzy", "ricky", "sally", "sandy", "tom", "vanesa", "zoe"],
     pages = names.reduce( (ps,n) => ps[n[0].toUpperCase()] ? (ps[n[0].toUpperCase()].push(n), ps)
                                                            : (ps[n[0].toUpperCase()] = [n], ps)
                         , {}
                         );
console.log(pages);
```

Comment: `A: (2) ['Ant','Animal']
B: ['BLADE']
E: (2) ['ELDER ']
N: (3) ['NUTELLA', 'NUTRIENT'.'NO']`

@Redu For example my array return some above list how to iterate and display these records in form of Pagination in JS ?

Comment: You are basically expected to display page anchors with the keys (A,B, ... ,Z) holding the links to the page HTML which is  in charge of displaying the correponding array items. Implementing this functionality totally depends on your choice of a framework or vanilla JS.